# How to define hash table?

Tags: linked-list, hashtable, cs50

I'm having problem understanding why do we* use node as data-type?
*(I'm doing CS50 and while solving problem sets it's givel like this)

```
node *hashtable[50];
```

(here node refers to linked list node)
as we are just storing an pointer for a linked list in it, wouldn't it be better to define it as just an array of char*

```
char *hashtable[50];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashing functions have collisions. When a key hashes to an index where the table is already occupied, one strategy to resolve the collisions have a linked list there and you simply append to it.

There are other [collision resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) strategies, but the [separate chaining strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) is probably the simplest.

In order to be able to treat the hash table items as linked lists, they need to have at least a `next` pointer in addition to their payload. Hence the items need to be some kind of `struct node*` rather than the payload type directly.

Comment: So their "payload" is also a pointer and "next" function also the same?

Comment: Or one of them is empty?